# 'node run' command in BASH shell scripting

Tags: node.js

I don't know what to do with 'node run' command so I just simply put it in a script and get the error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
'rror: Cannot find module 'C:\run
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

How do I run the command to start up an instance?

Comment: You want to run a JavaScript file?

Comment: it's javascript file with he shebang line #!/usr/bin/env node. Not sure what to write in bash script

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple, you must have a `app.js` or `run.js` file right ?

dir the right directory and then:

```
node you_file.js
```

(.js is not mendatory)

Comment: cd instead of dir. From your error `C:\run` I presumed you are using windows.

Comment: This is what I guessed from you previous command. Did you get it to work ?

Answer (score 1):

Node is an interpreter. If you just want the interactive interpreter, type just `node`. If you want to run a javascript program, you need to pass the path to your program to node like `node myprogram.js`.

Answer (score 0):

if for instance you have a script called hello.js and your terminal/cmd prompt is open to that directory you would simply type:

```
node hello
```

this is the same as:

```
node hello.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file's called "run", you have the shebang line you mentioned, the file's permissions are set to executable, and the directory it's located in is on your path, all you need is just plain "run" (if the directory isn't on your path, you need to specify its path).